# Trouble Getting Downloaded Model With Textures To Appear

Tags: texturing, image

I have been having trouble getting the textures to become visible in Render Mode. I am still very new to Blender and have been learning most things through Youtube tutorials. I have followed multiple tutorials but nothing seems to work to make these textures appear.

[image]

Maybe this can provide more insight

Comment: how is the render? send print

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Xa4ae6w This is what shows for the Render

Comment: already checked the shaders and images?

Comment: Sorry I'm still really new to this. Where could I find this?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/yoen64

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/g89g7On

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119477/discussion-between-salad-dalas-and-3d-ited).